# Letting the user open a file in a default program in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

If I do something like download a PDF from dropbox, for example, there is an 'open in' option that lets me do things like share the file, open it in various programs, print it, etc.

Seems to be standard Apple stuff.

I am writing a CSV file in my app in Swift, and when complete, I would then like to allow the user to open this file in the same manner as above (letting them attach this to an e-mail, print, open in an app of their choice, etc).

I'm having a harder time than I thought finding the code to do something like this. Any pointers to get me started in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a UIActivityViewController or, for sharing out a downloaded file, a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Thanks - these are just standard things I'd instantiate, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Read the documentation. Or you could consult my book. UIActivityViewController: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view UIDocumentationInteractionController: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_handing_off_a_document